# Getting all permutations of N-length

Tags: objective-c, set

Given an input NSArray, I am trying to return all unique permutations that have a length of n. The ordering is not important. My code works when n is 0 or 1. However, if n is bigger than 1 it also returns all the computed permutations that have a length that is lower than n. I only want the permutations that are of length n.

Here is my code:

```
+ (NSMutableSet *) combinations: (NSArray *) inputArray n: (int) n {
NSMutableSet *permutations = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
[ permutations addObject: [[NSSet alloc] init] ];

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    NSMutableSet *newPermutations = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    for (int j=0; j<[inputArray count]; j++) {
        NSSet *single = [NSSet setWithObjects:inputArray[j],nil];
        for (id permutation in permutations) {
            NSSet *newPermutation = [permutation setByAddingObjectsFromSet:single];
            [newPermutations addObject: newPermutation];
        }
    }
    permutations = [newPermutations copy];
}

return permutations;
}
```

Can anyone spot what is wrong here? I start with an empty set, then bread-first wise expand it. By assigning the newPermutations variable to permutations after each loop it should remove all the permutations from the previous level.
This is my first day using Objective-C so I don't know why it is not behaving like I think it should.

Comment: If you don't care about order, then you have _combinations_, not _permutations_.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the bug. I am combining sets while looping through all the input array elements for each level. Adding an element that already exists in the set does not make it longer and I overlooked that.

So the fix was to add an extra check to see if the newPermutation variable has indeed grown by 1 before adding it to the newPermutations set.

Answer (score 0):

What you are building are actually combinations, not permutations; permutations are ordered. You're just choosing subsets of your original collection.

I think there's an easier way to do this. Your desired result is very similar to [All possible combinations without repetition from an NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24467519/603977), adding your restriction on the size of the combinations. The same technique that I recommended there will work here: count to 2<sup>num_items</sup> and use `objectsAtIndexes:` to create the subarrays.

As in the other question, this only works for arrays whose count is 64 or less, but this should be reasonable: the number of combinations of size *k* from a collection of size *n* is called ***n choose k***, which can be calculated by *n! / (k!(n-k)!)*. This grows **very** quickly with *n* unless *k* is either small or close to *n*. For example, ***64 choose 12*** is 3,284,214,703,056. You don't have enough memory for that.

To adapt my answer there, we just need to be able to count the number of bits that are set in the index variable. This is called "popcount" (population count), and is very conveniently provided [as a builtin function by the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25748068/). In particular, we'll use the `__builtin_popcountll()` version, which operates on an `unsigned long long`.

This demonstrates the technique (using the `NSIndexSet` category method that I shared in the other answer). If you so choose, this could easily be put into a category method `-[NSArray QNAllSubarraysOfSize:(uint64_t)]`.

```
NSArray * items = @[...];

uint64_t subarray_size = ...;

NSMutableArray * combos = [NSMutableArray array];
// Loop through all possible index subsets
for( uint64_t index_mask = 0; index_mask < UINT64_MAX; index_mask++ ){
    // Check the size of this subset; pass if it's not right.
    uint64_t num_set_bits = __builtin_popcountll(index_mask)
    if( num_set_bits != subarray_size ){
        continue;
    }

    // If the size is correct, collect the subarray
    NSIndexSet * indexes = [NSIndexSet WSSIndexSetFromMask:index_mask];
    [combos addObject:[items objectsAtIndexes:indexes]];
}
```